# In c#.Net using IoC, is it OK to pass dependency to a method directly without using constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am new to IoC and I am struggling to understand if it is OK to pass a dependency to a method directly? I am using Unity IoC.

So lets say I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class FtpCommon : IFtpCommon
{
    private readonly IConfigSettings _config;

    public FtpCommon(IConfigSettings config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public string CombinePaths(string uri1, string uri2)
    {
        ....
    }        

    public string GetLocalFilteredFilePathsFull()
    {
        ....
    }        
    ....
}
```

Now, in one of the methods I need to use a dependency on a different class and at the moment I am doing it like this:

```
public List<FtpListItem> GetFtpFileListRecursive(IFtpClient ftp)
{
    ...
}
```

The reason I am passing ftp instance to the method directly, is because the ftp instance by that point is configured how I need.

However I've been reading up on different articles saying that all dependencies should be passed in a constructor, but I don't understand if this is the kind of dependency that should be moved to a class variable and passed down in a constructor, or are those kind of dependencies OK? And how would I do that?

Can someone experienced please comment on this?

Comment: How you call your method?

Comment: Inside a calling class I have this line: `List<FtpListItem> remoteFileList = _ftpCommon.GetFtpFileListRecursive(_ftp);` And that `_ftp` variable is the private injected variable of the calling class. As is `_ftpCommon`

Comment: I think your question would be a better fit for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no "rule" for IoC, as a generalised pattern, that says injection must occur via constructors only.

Further, https://unity.codeplex.com/ states,

> "The Unity Application Block (Unity) is a lightweight extensible
>   dependency injection container with support for constructor, property,
>   and method call injection."

So carry on as you are...

Comment: Method and property injection are rather frowned upon when done by a container. Also, with a Di container method injection is only done to make a dependency available, not to perform some work like `GetFtpFileListRecursive`. So the quote from unity does not apply here.